# How to get the bounds coordinates from GeoJson coordinates?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

I have data geosjon figuring out a polygon like this, and I want to overlay the raster data tif/jpg format overlay exact on that polygon

```
{
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "id": 1,
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "MultiPolygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                [
                                    98.936758936000047,
                                    3.5082781320000436
                                ],
                                [
                                    98.936761946000047,
                                    3.5082901750000701
                                ],
                                [
                                    98.936760674000084,
                                    3.508289742000045
                                ],
                                [
                                    98.936758936000047,
                                    3.5082781320000436
                                ]
                                ...and so on...
                            ]
                        ],
    .....
```

How can I get the bounds coordinates with this format [[x.xx, x.xx], [x.xx, x.xx]] from above geojson in react ?

My initial script:

```
import { latLngBounds } from 'leaflet'
```

So far, I can get the coordinates

```
datajson.features.map((state) => {
    const coordinates = state.properties.coordinates[0].map((item) => {
    [item[1], item[0]];
    console.log("The LatLng coordinate:" + coordinates);
    const boundsCordinate = latLngBounds(coordinates) 
   })
})
```

My Map

```
<ImageOverlay
        url="image url"
        bounds={[[x.xx, x.xx], [x.xx, x.xx]]}
      />
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you render the Geojson on the map or you just need it to take the bounds in order to set the ImageOverlay bounds?

Comment: I use this function layer.getBounds().getNorthEast() and layer.getBounds().getSouthWest() and it works perfectly